# Why i can not access file second time NSData Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

I need to attach file to my email. 
I created mail controller:

`let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()`

Then i use FileManager to get a path to my PDF file:

```
let filemgr = FileManager.default
let dirPaths = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let docsURL = dirPaths[0]
let newDir = docsURL.appendingPathComponent("folder").path
```

After that i get the file with NSData and attach it:

```
if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: newDir+"/file.pdf") {
    mail.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "file.pdf")
}
```

And then using "present" i sent it to email form:

```
present(mail, animated: true)
```

It's ok. File has been attached. But if i cancel sending the email and try to attach it again i dont see my file. After rebuild application i can attach file once again. What is wrong?

Comment: @YvetteColomb why protected? seems like mistake since it was protected in 2 minutes

Comment: @Miknash have a read of this https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions

Comment: @YvetteColomb sorry, but still don't get protected flag - quote: 'Questions should be protected when they are garnering lots of views and newbies are adding "me too!", "thanks!" and possibly even spam non-answers.'. Also, 'Any question at least a day old can be protected and unprotected by users that have the privilege, provided the question has received at least one answer from a user with less than 10 reputation (such users would then be prevented from posting further answers after the question is protected).'

Comment: @Miknash it means there's been answers posted, that have been deleted, and protecting the question means a user needs more than 10 rep. This way a spammer coming onto the site with a new account, cannot post an answer. Don't forget you cannot see the deleted answers.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarification

Comment: Have you implemented the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol?